# input box moving when selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a search field at the top of my site that when your selected it jumps up abit out of position and when you click out of the box so it's not selected but not close it the search field is aligned correctly. I can't figure out what is going on to make it move while the cursor is in the input field.

https://www.argentscientific.com

Click the link then click the search icon on the right side of the top level menu and you will see the problem. Rather confused about this one.

Comment: White on white... but I don't see the issue... Also JS script errors like it's going out of style!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of `:focus` is not being included. When you select the search input, `:focus` is triggered but there is an existing css that overwrite your css, to fix this you need to explicitly include `:focus` into your css to prevent it being overwritten. Try changing below css from

```
.aws-container .aws-search-field{
    width: 100%;
    color: #313131;
    padding: 6px;
    line-height: 30px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    background: rgb(247, 247, 247);
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

to

```
.aws-container .aws-search-field, .aws-container .aws-search-field:focus {
    width: 100%;
    color: #313131;
    padding: 6px;
    line-height: 30px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    background: rgb(247, 247, 247);
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```